# data loaded on page in untidy manner

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a page which has like many panels or boxes inside it. left side navigation, world map in the center, 3 small charts below it. When this page is loaded, it loads the data inside the containers in a very haphazard manner, the center world map moves down and up and then loads the map and similarly the 3 charts below. when I click a particular location on the map again the 3 charts below are updated as they should be but thier containers move around up and down when refreshed with new data.

I am using Grails for front end pages and html, with js, jquery with ajax calls on clicks. there are divs with classes used inside html tables to for the containers.

the locations of all components and containers is finally proper, but when anything is refereshed or page is loaded the containers juggle around a lot until the data is loaded..
making the page load animation very distorted.

How do I make all the containers fixed in position even when there is any refresh to a part of the page..

Regards
Priyank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways you might tackle this problem, which you could use in combination:

**1) use css to give all the containers a fixed width and height.** This way the layout won't jump around as the content loads.

**2) hide the contents of the containers, and only show them after everything has loaded**. You could have each ajax call set a flag when it completes and then check to see if all the other flags are set. If so, unhide all the content.